# Constant SPAM question

Tags: support, spam

During the last week the same SPAM entry has been posted to WPSE, something about a moving company from India. This question has been posted daily to the site from different users, but I suspect that is from the same user that uses different names. Is there a way to not just block a user in such a case but the IP that the spam is coming from.

I think I flagged that same entry about 5 times now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the experience from Bengali Wikipedia I can share that, we do have IP block in there, and due to such kind of blocking many users often experience that he/she is blocked without any guilt — because their IP somehow matches the blocked IP of a guilty person.

It happens because in many regions, Internet connection is a dial up connection, and with every entry into the connection, a new IP address generates.

So, to prevent the continuous spamming, I think IP blocking can be a way, but it has some other conflicts too. So, in that case, I think it's a continuous process, and we all are doing so, reporting, and admins are doing so, deleting again and again.